# Angular `font: inherit` breaks fonts

Tags: angular

In **Angular** If I use `font: inherit` style on my component fonts stop working and appear as `▢`

`app.component.html`

```
<i class="fas fa-car"></i>
```

`app.component.css`

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css");

i {
  font: inherit;
}
```

Stackblitz: [**Angular Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6bqj4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

I thought I was breaking something within the font awesome library but surprisingly the exact same markup with raw **HTML/CSS** works fine

```html
<head>
  <style>
    @import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css");
    
    i {
      font: inherit;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `font-family: inherit;` instead of `font`?

Comment: As Gowtham answered below, It `font-family: inherit` would still overwrite `font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free` for the icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need `font: inherit`. Font awesome sets the correct font family already.

**Why It works in plain HTML/CSS:**

In case of your html/css example, it works because of css specificity, your style `i { font: inherit; }` is overridden by font-awesome css as
**class** takes precedence over **html tags**

**Why it doesn't work in Angular**

Angular adds scope so that the css you apply for one component doesn't affect the other. If you inspect your html, you will find attributes like `_ngcontent-*` and your css being scoped like

```
i[_ngcontent-*] {
    font: inherit;
}
```

And **tag+attribute** takes precedence over font-awesome css **class** and that's why icon doesn't appear.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1):

In your case, style on `i` element is generated with random attribute that overrides `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"` which is necessary for the car icon to be drawn.